# Fields and Conservation of Energy

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, classical-field-theory

I am a bit confused about fields, like magnetic fields, and the conservation of energy.

For example, when two magnets are attracted to each other, don't they "exhaust" the field? The moon that orbits the Earth, why wouldn't it crash into the Earth having "exhausted" the gravitational "field"?

If we think quantum mechanically, the exchange particles "move" back and forth, hence manifesting themselves as forces and this "exchange" don't involve the exhaustion of anything. The number of particles is conserved. (Ok, perhaps this is not quite a correct description, but you get the idea.)

But what about thinking classically? There must be a misconception for me somewhere. I'd appreciate hearing from you all to clear this confusion. (You may write at a level of rigor a first, second year graduate student can understand.) Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by exhausting the field. In the case of two magnets, if you let them move freely as they attract each other, they accelerate towards each other, whereby the energy in the magnetic field is converted to kinetic energy (I suppose you can say the magnetic field is exhausted in this sense). In the case of the Earth - Moon system since the Moon's orbit is elliptical, there is a (roughly) periodic conversion between kinetic and gravitational potential energy, where the latter is greatest when the bodies are closest.

Answer (score 1):

“Exhaust”, in the sense of wear out from repetition, doesn’t really apply here.

When two magnets are attracted and move closer, the total field (total over all space) does go down. That means less energy is stored in it; the energy that’s no longer in the field goes into the motion of the magnets. The field drops because two opposite poles are getting closer and more intense parts of their fields are cancelling.

Similarly, if you push two N poles together, you have to add energy to do that. That added energy does into a *more* intense field, from the two N poles being closer.

(The exact field shapes that do this need to be looked at carefully: note that energy is stored in all the field, not just the parts right between the magnets)

But if something is just constantly circling, it’s not changing the energy at all.  The field doesn’t wear out from use in any way; it’s not consumed or exhausted. It just sits there, the same, not changing energy and not doing work on any object.